# Chunked file uploads with Laravel & AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I try to create a script to upload large files, I send data through Ajax (It's work), but this did not solve the problem of large files, in the best circumstances, I can upload only 100 MB, and this is not good for the user, can you help me to add **Chunked file uploads**, Thank you

This is my **HTML**:

```
<form id="upload_form" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 @csrf
 <input type="file" name="file" id="file-7" class="inputfile inputfile-6" />
<center>
   <a href="#" id="star_up" value="hide/show">
      <input class="btn btn-info btn-lg wow tada" id="sell_house_submit" type="submit" name="upload_file" value="@lang('lang.UPLOAD')">
   </a>
</center>
<div id="prog" style="display:none;">
    <progress id="progressBar" class="wow tada" style="@if(isMobile())width:200px;@else width:750px;@endif height: 10px;" value="0" max="100">
    </progress>
    <h3 class="av" id="status" ></h3>
    <p id="loaded_n_total" ></p>
```

My **javascript**:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 $('#upload_form').on('submit', function(event){
   $.ajax({
   url:"{{ route('upload') }}",
   method:"POST",
   data: new FormData(this),
   xhr: function() {
        var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
        if(myXhr.upload){
            myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress',progressHandler, false);
            myXhr.addEventListener("load", completeHandler, false);
            myXhr.addEventListener("error", errorHandler, false);
            myXhr.addEventListener("abort", abortHandler, false);
        }
        return myXhr;
    },
   dataType:'JSON',
   contentType: false,
   cache: false,
   processData: false,
   // IF SUCCESS
   success:function(data)
   {
      if (data.type_is == 'swal') {
        swal({
            title: data.title,
            html: data.html,
            showCloseButton: true,
            focusConfirm: false,
            type: data.status
        });
        jQuery('#progress_up').toggle('hide');
        document.getElementById('file-7').value = '';
        document.getElementById('name_file').innerHTML = '';
      } 
   }
  })
    event.preventDefault();
 });

});
```

**Controller**:

```
protected function upload(Request $request) {
  ini_set('max_execution_time', 3000);
  ini_set('memory_limit','256M');

  // UPLOAD FILE
  if (getValue('storage_type', 'disk') == 's3') {
     $path = Storage::disk('s3')->putFile('files', $request->file('file'));
     $storage = 's3';
  } else {
  $path = Storage::putFile('files', $request->file('file'));
  $storage = 'disk';
  }
  // RANDOM
  $link_id = Random();
  $delete_token = Random(50);
  $preview = Random(10);
  $ip = getip();

  $this->createFile($name, $path, $link_id, $delete_token, $ip, $preview, $size, $mime, $type, $storage);

  // FILE UPLOADED

  return response()->json([
     'title' => trans('lang.GREAT'),
     'html' => getFileInfoHTML($link_id, $delete_token, $name, $type, $preview),
     'type_is' => 'swal',
     'status' => 'success'
  ]);
}
```

I put the most important things only, I did not put the details of the file review and size ...., I just want to know how can I add the property and upload files **without a large RAM** :)

Comment: I think this is the code to use : [jQuery-File-Upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Chunked-file-uploads)? but I don't know how to use it!

Comment: You can try this package: https://packagist.org/packages/pion/laravel-chunk-upload

Comment: Yes, I know but what about AJAX ? how to send data with **maxChunkSize**?

Comment: pion/laravel-chunk-upload support  https://github.com/23/resumable.js for frontend ajax handle.

Comment: Thank you, but can you help me by adding the answer with the script, and I prefer to use AJAX because the upload works well through it, thank you

Comment: Can i use laravel-chunk-upload package it for multiple files and chunk upload? @Md.SukelAli

Answer (score 11):

1. Install pion/laravel-chunk-upload,

   ```bash
   composer require pion/laravel-chunk-upload

   php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Pion\Laravel\ChunkUpload\Providers\ChunkUploadServiceProvider"
   ```
2. Add route

   ```
   Route::post('/upload', 'UploadController@upload');
   ```
3. Add View and Scripts

   ```
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/resumable.js/1.1.0/resumable.min.js"></script>

   <script>
           var $ = window.$; // use the global jQuery instance

           var $fileUpload = $('#resumable-browse');
           var $fileUploadDrop = $('#resumable-drop');
           var $uploadList = $("#file-upload-list");

           if ($fileUpload.length > 0 && $fileUploadDrop.length > 0) {
               var resumable = new Resumable({
                   // Use chunk size that is smaller than your maximum limit due a resumable issue
                   // https://github.com/23/resumable.js/issues/51
                   chunkSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024, // 1MB
                   simultaneousUploads: 3,
                   testChunks: false,
                   throttleProgressCallbacks: 1,
                   // Get the url from data-url tag
                   target: $fileUpload.data('url'),
                   // Append token to the request - required for web routes
                   query:{_token : $('input[name=_token]').val()}
               });

           // Resumable.js isn't supported, fall back on a different method
               if (!resumable.support) {
                   $('#resumable-error').show();
               } else {
                   // Show a place for dropping/selecting files
                   $fileUploadDrop.show();
                   resumable.assignDrop($fileUpload[0]);
                   resumable.assignBrowse($fileUploadDrop[0]);

                   // Handle file add event
                   resumable.on('fileAdded', function (file) {
                       // Show progress pabr
                       $uploadList.show();
                       // Show pause, hide resume
                       $('.resumable-progress .progress-resume-link').hide();
                       $('.resumable-progress .progress-pause-link').show();
                       // Add the file to the list
                       $uploadList.append('<li class="resumable-file-' + file.uniqueIdentifier + '">Uploading <span class="resumable-file-name"></span> <span class="resumable-file-progress"></span>');
                       $('.resumable-file-' + file.uniqueIdentifier + ' .resumable-file-name').html(file.fileName);
                       // Actually start the upload
                       resumable.upload();
                   });
                   resumable.on('fileSuccess', function (file, message) {
                       // Reflect that the file upload has completed
                       $('.resumable-file-' + file.uniqueIdentifier + ' .resumable-file-progress').html('(completed)');
                   });
                   resumable.on('fileError', function (file, message) {
                       // Reflect that the file upload has resulted in error
                       $('.resumable-file-' + file.uniqueIdentifier + ' .resumable-file-progress').html('(file could not be uploaded: ' + message + ')');
                   });
                   resumable.on('fileProgress', function (file) {
                       // Handle progress for both the file and the overall upload
                       $('.resumable-file-' + file.uniqueIdentifier + ' .resumable-file-progress').html(Math.floor(file.progress() * 100) + '%');
                       $('.progress-bar').css({width: Math.floor(resumable.progress() * 100) + '%'});
                   });
               }

           }


   </script>


   <div class="text-center" >
       <div id="resumable-error" style="display: none">
           Resumable not supported
       </div>
       <div id="resumable-drop" style="display: none">
           <p><button id="resumable-browse" data-url="{{ url('upload') }}" >Upload</button> or drop here
           </p>
           <p></p>
       </div>
       <ul id="file-upload-list" class="list-unstyled"  style="display: none">

       </ul>
       <br/>
   </div>
   ```
4. In Your UploadController,

   ```php
   <?php
   namespace App\Http\Controllers;
   use Storage;
   use Illuminate\Http\Request;
   use Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile;
   use Pion\Laravel\ChunkUpload\Exceptions\UploadMissingFileException;
   use Pion\Laravel\ChunkUpload\Handler\AbstractHandler;
   use Pion\Laravel\ChunkUpload\Handler\HandlerFactory;
   use Pion\Laravel\ChunkUpload\Receiver\FileReceiver;
   class UploadController extends Controller
   {
       /**
        * Handles the file upload
        *
        * @param Request $request
        *
        * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
        *
        * @throws UploadMissingFileException
        * @throws \Pion\Laravel\ChunkUpload\Exceptions\UploadFailedException
        */
       public function upload(Request $request) {
           // create the file receiver
           $receiver = new FileReceiver("file", $request, HandlerFactory::classFromRequest($request));
           // check if the upload is success, throw exception or return response you need
           if ($receiver->isUploaded() === false) {
               throw new UploadMissingFileException();
           }
           // receive the file
           $save = $receiver->receive();
           // check if the upload has finished (in chunk mode it will send smaller files)
           if ($save->isFinished()) {
               // save the file and return any response you need, current example uses `move` function. If you are
               // not using move, you need to manually delete the file by unlink($save->getFile()->getPathname())
               return $this->saveFile($save->getFile());
           }
           // we are in chunk mode, lets send the current progress
           /** @var AbstractHandler $handler */
           $handler = $save->handler();
           return response()->json([
               "done" => $handler->getPercentageDone(),
               'status' => true
           ]);
       }
       /**
        * Saves the file to S3 server
        *
        * @param UploadedFile $file
        *
        * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
        */
       protected function saveFileToS3($file)
       {
           $fileName = $this->createFilename($file);
           $disk = Storage::disk('s3');
           // It's better to use streaming Streaming (laravel 5.4+)
           $disk->putFileAs('photos', $file, $fileName);
           // for older laravel
           // $disk->put($fileName, file_get_contents($file), 'public');
           $mime = str_replace('/', '-', $file->getMimeType());
           // We need to delete the file when uploaded to s3
           unlink($file->getPathname());
           return response()->json([
               'path' => $disk->url($fileName),
               'name' => $fileName,
               'mime_type' =>$mime
           ]);
       }
       /**
        * Saves the file
        *
        * @param UploadedFile $file
        *
        * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
        */
       protected function saveFile(UploadedFile $file)
       {
           $fileName = $this->createFilename($file);
           // Group files by mime type
           $mime = str_replace('/', '-', $file->getMimeType());
           // Group files by the date (week
           $dateFolder = date("Y-m-W");
           // Build the file path
           $filePath = "upload/{$mime}/{$dateFolder}/";
           $finalPath = storage_path("app/".$filePath);
           // move the file name
           $file->move($finalPath, $fileName);
           return response()->json([
               'path' => $filePath,
               'name' => $fileName,
               'mime_type' => $mime
           ]);
       }
       /**
        * Create unique filename for uploaded file
        * @param UploadedFile $file
        * @return string
        */
       protected function createFilename(UploadedFile $file)
       {
           $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
           $filename = str_replace(".".$extension, "", $file->getClientOriginalName()); // Filename without extension
           // Add timestamp hash to name of the file
           $filename .= "_" . md5(time()) . "." . $extension;
           return $filename;
       }
   }
   ```

**Note** that `saveFileToS3` is not a route, and you can optionally call `saveFileToS3(...)` method after upload is 100% (instead of calling `saveFile(...)` method).

Also, multiple and/or simultaneous uploads are supported by [resumable.js](https://github.com/23/resumable.js)

Comment:  Thank you !! I will try now !

Comment: But what about my AJAX options ? like progress ?

Comment: There is a action called fileProgress() will handle your progress. Just Try this code. everything added. You can even configure you chunk size.

Comment: The JS script references input[name=_token], this isn't present.  You'll need to add @csrf within the html portion of the blade file.